# Are there any compact microphones compatible with RasPi that can fit inside a typical enclosure?

Tags: usb, audio

It is my understanding that the Raspberry Pi doesn't have a sound card and therefore isn't able to accept sound input without help. However, most USB microphone have such a "sound card" built in, and I've read reports from many people who were able to record audio using their USB webcam's microphone.

I would like to record audio with my RasPi but need a very compact component. Ideally, I would like the microphone to be very tiny,such as the size of s small thumb drive, or small enough to add into a typical enclosure and have a hole drilled into the side of the case to stick the microphone part. I guess that would need some interface other than USB since it would be inside the case.

I bought [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Microfono-Studio-Speech-Super-Mini-USB-2-0-Wireless-Microphone-MIC-Audio-Adapter-Driver-For-MSN/32518872205.html?spm=2114.01020208.3.1.oiBSGa&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_1,searchweb201644_4_79_78_77_82_80_62_81,searchweb201560_8) one, and I could record, but it was so weak and without gain that I could barely hear anything. Any suggestions are very welcome!

Edit: So, I did try using `alsamixer` as per the commentator's advice, and I could find my PnP device and increased the mic's gain. I do think it made a difference, although not a massive one. Also, there is a ton of electric interference in the recording, with obvious buzzing, crackles, and pops. Even with the noise, the volume wasn't loud enough for my liking.

I would like to have better quality microphone recording. I'm wondering if I can just buy some USB microphone like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017D76YWA) one and hack it apart and take out the goodies for my application. Does anybody think that will get me better sound, or have other suggestions how to solve my dilemma?

Comment: Did you tried to use `alsamixer`? With this, you can make the recordings louder.

Comment: @Sirac Thanks for the tip, I'll test it out tonight using my RasPi 2 B+ and report back my findings.

Comment: @Sirac Please see my edit, I tried your suggestion!

Comment: So your microphone is too quiet for your purposes. Sadly, my knowledge of RPi-hardware is not big enough to help you with that. The only thing I could recommend is this: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1475
It might fit into a typical enclosure and you are not restricted to USB-microphones anymore.